# Reporting library for Linux / C++ / Gtk?

Tags: c++, linux, reporting, gtk, gtkmm

We have a C++ Gtk application that currently has a "homebrew" reporting component. We're looking to step up to a more fully-featured reporting library, preferably with a WYSIWYG designer, print-preview / GUI viewer, and PDF export capabilities.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of unclear exactly what you mean by "reporting component".  But you can do print-preview and PDF generation using Cairo, although that's fairly low-level.  At least it might be used as the basis for the reporting component you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use BIRT or JasperReports (open-source Java libraries, each one has a WYSIWYG designer available) and invoke it either by JNI or by executing the corresponding viewer in a subprocess?